# Como sanear y asignar dinámicamente un enlace a una etiqueta iframe si mi enlace esta contenido en un Json - Framework Angular

Tags: json, angular, iframe, src

tengo un inconveniente al querer cargar un enlace en el src de una etiqueta iframe, dado que me bota un error de que la ruta no es confiable, por lo cual e implementado sanitizer en mi componente de la siguiente forma:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ServiceEnlaceService} from '../../../services/service-enlace.service'
import { IEnlace } from 'src/app/Modelos/Enlace';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-productoslacteo',
  templateUrl: './productoslacteo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./productoslacteo.component.css']
})

export class ProductoslacteoComponent{
  
  productos:IProducto[]=[];
  enlaces:IEnlace[]=[];

  constructor(
    private serviceRE:ServiceEnlaceService,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    ){  }

  sanadorRuta(ruta?:any){
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(ruta)
  }

  onClickReporteId(idreporte?:number){

     this.serviceRE.getEnlacesByReporte(idreporte).subscribe(enlaces =>{
if(this.sanadorRuta(enlaces[0].enlace)){
  this.enlaces[0].enlace =  this.sanadorRuta(enlaces[0].enlace) // err:Type 'SafeResourceUrl' is 
                                                                //not assignable to type 'string'.
alert("ruta sanada")
}else{
  alert("ruta dudosa")
}
```

Este código lo he ido avanzando poco a poco pero no se si sea la forma adecuada de sanar los enlaces que se contengan en un json, dado que al momento de hacer el pase de "enlaces sanados" pues me da un error de tipos que no me permite almacenarlos. Agradecería cualquier ayuda o comentario sobre como poder solventarlo.

Para una mejor compresión del json que consumo:

```
 {
        "idenlace": 1,
        "nombreenlace": " análisis de datos ",
        "enlace": "https://enlacedepowerbi..."
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que tienes es porque la función retorna un objeto de tipo `SafeResourceUrl` y quieres guardarlo en una variable de tipo `string`.

Eso puedes arreglarlo guardando el resultado de la función en una variable nueva, ejemplo:

```
url = {
    normal: 'https://www.google.com.sv',
    sanitized: null
  };

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.url.sanitized = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
      this.url.normal
    );
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cm2knj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: al hacer eso me salta un error: Type 'SafeResourceUrl' is not assignable to type 'null'